# What is this print syntax? (print rightshift)

Tags: python, syntax, printing, python-2.7, bit-shift

Looking at [the source code of pstats](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pstats.py) I see this syntax:

```
print >> self.stream, "in %.3f seconds" % self.total_tt
print >> self.stream
```

What is this syntax, how is it called and how to use it? I have never seen it before, nor seen it in any of the Python books/tutorials I have read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the `>>`, that's the Python 2.x syntax for writing to a file-like other than `sys.stdout` with `print`. It's defined in the Python docs, [6.6. The print statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) and has been around since at least Python 2.5 (and I think earlier).

This syntax has been replaced with a `file` kwarg to the `print` function in Python 3.0.

Comment: It might be also helpful to think of it as python's version of fprintf, but instead of c's file handles, you specify a python "file-like object".

Answer (score 2):

It's the extended form of the print statement which redirects the output to the file-like object immediately following it. See the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).